# What is behaviour of cpp sort function, by using default overloaded greater function for vector<vector<int>>

Tags: c++, vector, clang++

Difference between `sort(begin(ans), end(ans))` vs `sort(begin(ans), end(ans), std::greater<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >())`

as `sort(begin(ans), end(ans))` works perfectly as expected where as specifing the greater doesn't works.

```
  vector<int> S = {12,13, 34, 9,10};
  vector<vector<int> >ans;
  vector<int> currSet;
  subset(0, S, currSet, ans);
  sort(begin(ans), end(ans), std::greater<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >());
  cout << ans.size();
}
```

give error

```
In file included from subset.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/bits/stdc++.h:52:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ccomplex:21:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/complex:247:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/sstream:174:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:138:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:505:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string_view:176:
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__string:57:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:3832:17: error: no
      matching function for call to object of type
      'std::__1::greater<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > >'
            if (__comp(*--__last, *__first))
                ^~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:4018:5: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::__sort<std::__1::greater<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int,
      std::__1::allocator<int> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int,
      std::__1::allocator<int> > > > > &, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >
      *>' requested here
    __sort<_Comp_ref>(__first, __last, __comp);
    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:4052:12: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::sort<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > *,
      std::__1::greater<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > > &>'
      requested here
    _VSTD::sort<_Tp*, _Comp_ref>(__first.base(), __last.base(), __comp);
           ^
subset.cpp:33:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::__1::sort<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >,
      std::__1::greater<std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > > > > >'
      requested here
  sort(all(ans), greater<vector<vector<int> > >());
  ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template prameter for `std::greater` needs to be the element type that the iterators point to.  Since the iterator for of `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` has a `value_type` of `std::vector<int>` (that's the type of the of the elements in `ans`) that is what you need.  That gives you

```
sort(begin(ans), end(ans), std::greater<std::vector<int> >());
```

as what you need.

---

Also note that a space is no longer required for the closing `>` in a template parameter list.  You can use

```
sort(begin(ans), end(ans), std::greater<std::vector<int>>());
```

and that will compile in a C++11+ compliant compiler.

Answer (score 4):

`std::greater<std::vector<std::vector<int> > >` is for comparing objects of type `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`. But the vector `ans` does not contain objects of that type. It contains objects of type `std::vector<int>`. Thus, the comparator that you need is `std::greater<std::vector<int>>`. Or, you could simply use `std::greater<>` which is simpler to read, write and less likely to result in a bug.